# ¿Cómo puedo insertar datos con tablas relacionadas en Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo un `Post` que tiene una `categoría` y que tiene un `estado` y aparte su `usuario` que lo hizo, se pueden imaginar las locuras que hice ne el código.

Mi idea es, que un usuario cuando haya iniciado sesión *(uso make:auth)* pueda crear `Post`, que este mismo le asigne una categoría a ese `Post`, por ejemplo la categoría `Computación` y que el `estado` por default sea `0`, este estado de ID 0 no existe, es decir, que los `Post` por default no tengan `estado`. Eso se logra en el `Schema` asignado un `->default(0)` en la tabla supongo.

- Un `Post` debe tener una categoría asignado por el usuario que lo creo
- Un `Post` puede tener un estado si es que un usuario administrador se lo asignó. *(Un estado es como por ejemplo "Verificado" o "En revisión")*
- Un `Post` ademas debe tener el usuario que lo creó.

Las categorías y los estados se crean en la administración :P

También mi idea es que se pueda filtrar por categoría o estados para mostrar los Post, como la mayoría de los sitios.

**Cabe destacar que a código puro lograría esto, pero estoy en proceso de aprendizaje con Laravel.**

Tengo mis modelo y mis migraciones:

- Modelos (mis relaciones):

Post.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this
    ->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function category()
{
    return $this
    ->hasOne('App\Category');
}

public function status()
{
    return $this
    ->hasOne('App\Status');
}
```

Category.php

```
public function posts()
{
return $this
->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

User.php

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this
    ->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

Status.php

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this
    ->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

- Migraciones

User

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Post

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('title', 120);

    $table->string('content', 680);

    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();

    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->default(0);;

    $table->integer('status_id')->unsigned()->default(0);

    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    $table->foreign('status_id')->references('id')->on('statuses');
});
```

Este es la ultima migración que se ejecuta, porque si no me da error de los `Foreign`

Category

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Status

```
Schema::create('statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**-------**

Y lo siguiente es el `código` loco para insertar un Post con una categoría, con un estado y con el usuario:

```
$post = new App\Post([
    'title' => 'Titulo de mi post',
    'content' => 'Lorem...'
]);

// La categoria 1 si existe, la tengo registrada
$category = App\Category::find(1); 
$post->category()->associate($category);

$status = App\Status::find(1);
$status->posts()->save($status);

$user = App\User::find(1);
$user->posts()->save($post);
```

Este ultimo codigo, todo, aparte de que esta mal (supongo) también ha sufrido miles de cambios. He visto ejemplos, pero solo para cuando es de relación `Muchos` a `Muchos`.

Mis relaciones son de `Uno` a `Muchos` o de `Uno` a `Uno`.

Comment: Y ... ¿cuál es el problema o qué es lo que no funciona?

Comment: El problema, es que el ultimo código que lo uso en un seed no me anda. Me sale error en la consola :(

Comment: ¿Qué error aparece?

Comment: Pues antes aparecía errores y era que había que agregar category_id o algo asi... Pero ahora el error que aparece es este: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::associate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay errores en la definición de las relaciones, normalmente una categoría tiene muchos posts y por consiguiente, un post pertenece a una categoría:

Modelo Post:

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

Modelo Category:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

Lo mismo ocurre con el estado:

Modelo Post:

```
public function status()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Status');
}
```

Modelo Status:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

---

También hay errores al momento de guardar las relaciones, teniendo en cuenta que son varias en el Post, se puede hacer:

```
$category = App\Category::find(1); 
$post->category()->associate($category);

$status = App\Status::find(1);
$post->status()->associate($status);

$user = App\User::find(1);
$post->user()->associate($user);

$post->save();
```

Comment: Me sale esto: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'status_id' in 'field list' (SQL: update `statuses` set `updated_at` = 2019-02-12 16:36:40, `status_id` = 1 where `id` = 1)`

Comment: Revisa la edición que hice, al parecer estás asociando incorrectamente los modelos.

Comment: Ah pues tenes razón, si me funcionó jajaja gracias men!